# When can a regular simplex be inscribed in a regular hypercube?

Tags: simplex, polytopes

A cube's vertices can be trivially divided into two sets, each forming the vertices of a regular tetrahedron. I was wondering if such a construction could be generalized to higher dimensions.

I've found [here](http://hi.gher.space/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=2468) a set of coordinates for the $7$-simplex, which imply that it can be inscribed in a $7$-hypercube. (There’s a pretty cool connection to projective geometry there). So, I'm only aware of the cases $n=3,7$ at the moment.

For a particular dimension $n$, we could check the cases for all possible edge lengths of the $n$-simplex: if we choose a vertex and an edge length, we can check whether our remaining points allow us to build the $(n-1)$-simplex of correct edge length we need to build our $n$-simplex. I've checked $n=4$, doesn't seem to work. But this approach doesn't seem generalizable.

We could also try to construct examples by playing around with the coordinates of the hypercube $(\pm1,\pm1,\ldots,\pm1)$, but so far I haven't found anything.

So, for which dimensions can a regular $n$-simplex be built from the vertices of a regular $n$-hypercube?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: Solving via Maple for the case $n=4$, there does not exist a regular $4$-simplex whose $5$ vertices are vertices of a $4$-cube.

Comment: @quasi Doesn’t this contradict the $n=7$ example? I’ve checked it and it certainly seems to work out.

Comment: This question is treated in different articles. See for example Theorem 4.5 in [this reference](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Markov.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rows of a Hadamard matrix form a regular simplex.
Hadamard matrices are known for many multiples of 4 including all multiples of 4 up to 664.  $n$ is one less than the multiple of 4.

Comment: A regular $(n-1)$-simplex perhaps, but the OP's question was whether the $n+1$ vertices of a regular $n$-simplex can be taken from the vertices of an $n$-cube.

Comment: @quasi Given a Hadamard matrix of size $n$, each row may be kept or inverted, such that the first entry of every row becomes equal. The new matrix remains a Hadamard matrix. Reading each row as a point then creates an $(n-1)$-simplex embedded in an $(n-1)$-hypercube.

Comment: It would be cool to know whether this is an if and only if condition.

Comment: Yep, it is. Jean Marie's reference on my post confirms this via theorem 5.3.