# Measurements on 7 dimensional cube

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-geometry, polytopes, semidefinite-programming

For a particular problem, I think I've found a way to solve it by translating it into a 7-dimensional cube. Basically, I'll associate the vertices of the cube with some objects and would have to find the optimal way to arrange them based on the edges between the vertices( say an arrangement with a minimum number of edges).

I need to know the go-to method for solving such problems. I've heard of polymake before. Can I use it for my use? Where can I find more help?

EDIT :The problem

I have eight 7 bit strings (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h). I think I can find suitable vertices for them in a 7 dimensional cube. Now, I need to find two vertices (X, Y) such that, when we partition the eight strings to two sets and associate the two sets with our two new vertices, the sum of the  number of edges connecting the chosen vertices(X, Y) with the strings in their corresponding sets should be a minimum.

For eg. If we partition the eight strings to (a, c, e) and (b, d, f, g, h) and associate X and Y with them respectively, then, the sum would be given by adding the number of edges between X-a, X-c and X-e and Y-b, Y-d, Y-f, Y-g, Y-h. The problem is to find the optimum partition and the optimum choice of vertices such that this sum is minimum.

My vertices are:

1. `0000000`
2. `0010111`
3. `0101101`
4. `0111010`
5. `1001011`
6. `1011100`
7. `1100110`
8. `1110001`

Comment: The family of problems you have in mind is not clear, at least to this Reader, so I find it difficult to advise you about any "go-to method for solving such problems."  Perhaps you have in mind a [Hamiltonian tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) of the vertices of a polytope?

Comment: ah yes, sorry...  It's a little hard to explain but ill try... Check the edit

Comment: Thanks for the added information.  I take it that assignment of eight objects $a,b,\ldots,h$ to vertices of the $7$-cube is fixed.  There are $2^7 = 128$ possible vertices, so plenty of choices are left for "new" vertices $X,Y$.  You want to vary both the choices of $X,Y$ and the choice of bipartition to minimize the total edges between the new vertices and the vertices assigned to their respective parts.

Comment: By number of edges between two vertices, do you mean the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between corresponding pair of 7-bit binary strings? Your problem sounds like some sort of [2-clustering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) using hamming distances.

Comment: @hardmath once $X,Y$ are chosen, the assignment of partition is simple. For each string, assign it to partition 1 if it is closer to $X$ than $Y$ and partition $2$ otherwise.

Comment: @achillehui: I did not take that to be the objective function to minimize, but let's hope the OP clarifies.

Comment: @hardmath Yes,  I want to vary both the partition and the choices of the new vertices so that I get the minimum number of edges.

Comment: @achillehui Hamming distance was precisely the term I was looking for. I don't think it is a clustering problem as I want the total distance to be the minimum rather than minimizing over each cluster.

Comment: Also, I believe that these two new strings would be inverses of each other. Hope that helps.

Comment: Each of the eight vertices is 4 edges away from every other vertex

Comment: In effect, you have just inscribed a 7-dimensional _regular simplex_ into a cube of the same dimension, much like you can do in 3D (but not in 4, 5, or 6).

Comment: @IvanNeretin wow I didnt know that it was impossible in 4,5,6 dimensions...the number 7 has some significance to the problem that I'm working on right now...can you point me to some proofs on this impossibility?

Comment: @IvanNeretin So is such a form possible in 15 dimensions?

Comment: Why, that's trivial. A vertex of an $n$-dimensional unit cube is $\sqrt{n}\over2$ away from the center. A simplex with that circumradius has an edge of $\sqrt{n+1\over2}$. Now see whether you have two vertices of your cube which are exactly that far apart. As for 15: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Nice...Do you think my problem could be reformulated in terms of this?

Comment: See [this earlier Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645941/when-can-a-regular-simplex-be-inscribed-in-a-regular-hypercube) for using vertices of a hypercube to form a regular simplex.